# user defined square predicate

Tags: prolog

I am using SWI-Prolog V 6.2.3 on Windows 7. I have written the following predicates that calculate the absolute value and the square of an integer:

```
myabs(X,X):- X > = 0.

myabs(X,Y):- Y is -X.

mysq(X,S):- myabs(X,Y), S is Y * Y.
```

I get errors (operator error) for the following lines:

> 2 : Prolog does not seem to accept -X.
>
> 3 : Prolog does not seem to accept Y * Y (when replaced by 2 * 2, I don't get error)

I understand there are built-in predicates for these functions, but as I am new, these are small programs that help me learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a typo in rule 1: remove the space after `>`

```
myabs(X,X):- X >= 0.
myabs(X,Y):- Y is -X.
mysq(X,S):- myabs(X,Y), S is Y * Y.
```

then, after correction:

```
?- mysq(-3,X).
X = 9.
```

Are you aware that myabs is not required for squaring?

```
?- X = -3, Y is X*X.
X = -3,
Y = 9.
```

*edit* as @false noted, also myabs/2 needs a correction, to prevent wrong results when input is positive **and** backtracking is involved. Adding a guard to second clause could do:

```
myabs(X, Y):- X < 0, Y is -X.
```

but I would prefer the if/then/else construct, i.e. replacing those 2 clauses with

```
myabs(X, Y) :- X >= 0 -> Y is X ; Y is -X.
```

Comment: Thannnnnnnnnnnnnnnks!! Yes, I see that myabs is not required, but just using the rule to have a better understanding of how one user defined predicate can use another one.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the syntax error: Your definition of `myabs/2` does *not* compute the absolute value of a number. That is, it does compute it, but in addition it does something incorrect!

```
?- myabs(2,Abs).
   Abs = 2
;  Abs = -2.
```

So it says that the absolute value of two is *both* 2 and -2 which certainly is not correct.

Prolog uses each rule to derive solutions independently which means that you can read each rule alone.  There are ways to make rules dependent on each other, but let's keep it simple for the moment. Your second rule reads:

```
myabs(X,Y):- Y is -X.
```

The absolute value of `X` is the negated `X`. No matter what `X` is. So this rule also applies for `X` being `2`. You need a further condition here that `X` is negative.

As a beginner, better use `library(clpfd)` in place of `(is)/2` see [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)